# could not understand the concept of jsp_precompile

Tags: jsp

as mentioned in books ,when we append ?jsp_precompile to any query it will compile the files n further queries will be accessed faster.. 
now my question is "how to use this ?jsp_precompile"

1. whether to use in url written in code appended with "?jsp_precompile"
2. or to call this jsp page specially in the browser by appending this.

so. if it the first case then it is not working in mine, as when i do this the jsp page is called but has nothing in it.. the query that appears on browser has jsp_precompile appended to it or this may be related to my http://www.coderanch.com/t/615977/Tomcat/jsp-compiled-files-java-files this problem. (please try to answer this one also).

or if it is the 2nd case then why is the need of appending this in the end as calling a jsp from a browser will automatically compiles it.. what this jsp_precompile does special..

Answer (score 0):

See [this nice overview](http://javapapers.com/jsp/how-to-pre-compile-jsp/). One may conclude, that the it was a measure introduced later to be a standard (for the miscellaneous Java EE servers) to precompile JSPs. The JSP might not be run, only compiled! No other parameters should be given. That the JSP is actually run, is a server specific trait.

Nowadays there are other means from maven plugins to whatever.

Comment: please ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721498/why-my-jsp-s-compiled-files-i-e-java-files-n-class-files-are-not-visible-in-wor

Comment: n thanks in advance as you are doing a good job by answering the questions.. i also posted these questions almost a week before on a very famous java website n dint got any answer.. so i m happy now that i am getting my answers