# why my jsp 's compiled files i.e java files n class files are not visible in work folder

Tags: jsp

i know this may be a very silly questions to ask but i am really looking forward for its answer. 
i am practicing jsp and few days before when i created one jsp file ,the corresponding servlet was visible in work/catalina/localhost_ _ _. folder 
but now whatever projects i m creating ,all the jsp's are working fine but i am not able to find the compiled file in the work folder... 
what can be the problem now.. or eclipse might be the problem as where it is keeping those jsp compiled files.. 
please reply as soon as possible,,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833711/where-are-compiled-jsp-java-jsp-java-files

Comment: but the thing is this that my jsp files are compiled and working fine but not visible in the metioned file hierarchy .. my all previous projects are visible there with all jsp files but not the newly created one.. not a single project is appearing there.. but all have jsp files in them and are working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can *find* where the class resides (inside a jar or whatever), via:

```
<!-- This classes URL:
   <%= getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
           .getLocation().toExternalForm(); %>
-->
```

The getLocation delivers an URL.

Comment: yes, i got them there.. this solved my problem but still one question that now i cannot get those files in apache work folder???? as now they are residing in eclipse work folder. so its upto eclipse where it keeps the file or can we do some setting to make eclipse to again keep the files in apache work folder

Comment: eclipse might incorporate project directories immediately in the running web application. _Unfortunately I am not so the eclipse afficionado._ The entire WebContents folder.

Comment: thanks again.. i have one more question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723480/using-jspusebean-tag-without-class-attribute?noredirect=1#comment25833750_17723480

Comment: Sorry, cannot neglect my work; paraphrasing Shakespeare "to bean or not to bean."

Comment: i understand.. wherever you get time, try to answer.. thanks once again