# using <jsp:useBean tag without class attribute

Tags: jsp

i have a confusion in using usebean tag without class attribute, 
as the example given in head first servlets

and it says that the person bean must already exists, then only it will work.

1. so my question is that, is it possible that we can make this work because if the bean is already declared in page scope(then it must be declared in the same page ), and then if we use this line in same page it will give an exception of having duplicate bean.
2. and if we declare it in request scope then also in using it on different jsp page it gives exception "java.lang.InstantiationException:bean not found in the scope"
3. but if I declare it in session scope then it is working fine on the next jsp page.

so please solve my above mentioned questions

Comment: Answer to 1.
JSP is like Java, infact it is java. So you cannot create 2 instances with same name in same page.

Comment: so this means the example shown in this famous book is not possible..

Comment: head first servlets & jsp for ocpwcd and can you help me with other questions

Comment: sorry, i got the answer of 2 and 3... i was doing some silly mistake